# Need to add a hyperlink to a logo

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I've put a logo on my site's homepage and the logo was clickable. And then I adjusted its position through custom.css file, but now the logo is NOT clickable (plain image). How to make it clickable again?
Here's a homepage of my site:
[My site's URL](https://repetit.moscow)

Comment: Is this the element that you are referring to? `<a title="Ассоциация репетиторов" href="https://repetit.moscow/"><img class="pull-left" src="/images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>`  I am struggling to track down your css declaration (from my mobile phone), could you please edit your question to provide the exact html element (and potentially its parents) as well as your new css declaration? This way volunteers and future researchers will not need to visit your site to understand your question.

Comment: You think I've understood what you were asking? If I were qualified enough to understand all of that then I would've solved it myself. And yes that's the code of the logo to make it clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inspector in Chrome or Firefox to inspect the HTML + CSS. The issue with the non-clickable logo seems to be caused by the **float: left;** in your CSS. If you remove it, the logo is clickable again. However, the top bar won't look good; You have to solve that in another way.

```
#toolbar .float-left .module, #toolbar .float-left>time {
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: if you were able to delve into the OP's soite to extract the necessary details, please edit the question so that the current state of the logo element / document is not lost from this page when the OP fixes the website.

Comment: So what exactly should I do? If I just add those lines to custom.css, that's doesn't help...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the solution. I simply changed the last line of custom.css to this:

```
#toolbar .float-left .module:last-of-type {
float: none !important;
width: 100% !important; 
position: static; /* add to override its previous "module" ruling */
```

Comment: This page should have a green tick awarded -- the answer that you select may be your own.  Now that you have over 15 rep, you can upvote answers that you find helpful.  If pe7er's answer was helpful to you, you may show your appreciation by upvoting his answer.